# Conducted emissions testing for POE 802.3 device?

Tags: poe, certification, nrtl

For IoT devices with a Powered Device (PD) for Power Over Ethernet (POE) and not plugged into AC mains; What, if any, standards would a device potentially be subject to at an Nationally Recognized Testing Lab (NRTL)?

Are there also any conducted emissions standards for 802.3af or 802.3at certification?

Comment: They would probably tell you if you emailed them. I've done this in the past; just to confirm what testing standards that they can test to.

Comment: I actually asked Metlabs a while back and the rep couldn't tell me, have to submit an RFQ and I'm not ready to do that yet, but I would like to do precompliance.

Comment: Can you find a similar product and look up what it has been tested to either by looking at its label or, by trying to get hold of what in the UK/EU would be called a declaration/certificate of conformity?

Comment: Standards apply by sector/market. What is the market for your device? Multimedia? Industrial?

Comment: Business IoT, not industrial...

Comment: @Andyaka I've looked but they mainly say certified under 802.3af so I'm not sure if there is or isn't a conducted test as part of that standard.

Comment: @VoltageSpike, I think there needs to be a more precise market, because all markets necessarily fall within a standard. For example: EN55011 for industrial, scientific and medical devices, EN55032 multimedia equipment, EN55014 household electrical appliances, electric tools, etc... EN550xx standards deal with susceptibility, and refer to other standards for immunity. EN55011 refers to 61000-4 for immunity testing. EN55032 refers to CISPR16-1 for immunity testing.

Comment: It looks like a PD falls under 55022/ CISPR 22. I would be doing class A since its commercial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a PD falls under 55022/ CISPR 22. I would be doing class A since its commercial.

> The PD must comply with EMC standards, such as that defined by EN
> 55022 / CISPR 22, in order to be sold in many markets. The EN 55022 /
> CISPR 22 standard establishes limits for both conducted emissions and
> radiated emissions. The limits are defined for Class A (commercial)
> and Class B (residential) equipment, with Class B being the more
> stringent. The conducted emissions generated by a PD, which is
> considered to be a telecommunication port, are measured as common-mode
> disturbances on the CAT-5 cable. The radiated emissions associated
> with a PD can be in the form of emissions radiating from the CAT-5
> cable as a result of the PD’s conducted common-mode noise (i.e.
> antenna mode disturbances), or emissions that radiate directly from
> the PD itself.

Source: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua454/slua454.pdf?ts=1706213102228&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F